# Mongoose auto fill data by searching in reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    referrals: {
      ref: 'User',
      type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    },

    referredBy: {
      ref: 'User',
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    },
  }
);
```

I want Mongoose to find users who have current user _id in `referredBy` reference.

In other words, eg: find all users who have `'_IDOfSpecificUser'` in their `referredBy` field and put all the found users in the array of `referrals` where user's _id is `'_IDOfSpecificUser'`.

How can I handle that in mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is using `find`

```
User.
  find({ "referredBy" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx" }).
  exec(function (err, users) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The users are an array: ', users);
  });
```

Refer to https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

If you want to convert bellow function to static method inside UserSchema, please refer to this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-static and https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html